# Updating JEventDispatcher triggers

Tags: plugin, plugin-events, joomla-4.x, joomla-4

Can anyone explain or point me to information on the new way to handle events in Joomla 4? I'm updating a component that uses triggers to display plugins, and it looks like this:

```
$dispatcher = JEventDispatcher::getInstance();
$dispatcher->trigger('onBeforeRenderToolbar', array($settings));
```

In Joomla 4 this throws an error that there's no `JEventDispatcher` class-- but the new `Joomla\Event\Dispatcher` stuff doesn't make much sense to me and doesn't seem to have the same methods. The docs at https://docs.joomla.org/Supporting_plugins_in_your_component have not been updated to support the new syntax.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use Joomla\CMS\Factory;

Factory::getApplication()->triggerEvent('onBeforeRenderToolbar', array($settings));
```

This method can be used in 3.x too.

Comment: Thanks Sharky. I couldn't find any namepsaced class for `JEventDispatcher` in the classmap so was wondering for a moment whether to stick with it, or if there was another approach.